# List of ios device name

Tags: iphone, ipad, device, hardware-id

i have used this function in my app for return the model name of my device and work very well, but how i can find a complete list of the returned value for this function (es for iphone3,3gs,4s,ipad,ipad2,ipod ecc ecc

```
size_t size;  
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);  
char *machine = malloc(size);  
sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);  
NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithCString:machine];  
free(machine);  
return platform;
```

Thanks

Comment: You can find most of them here: https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/blob/master/UIDevice-Hardware.m

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use to get the all details of your mobile OS using `UIDevice` class as below:

```
NSLog(@"uniqueIdentifier: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"name: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);
NSLog(@"systemName: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]);
NSLog(@"systemVersion: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
NSLog(@"model: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
NSLog(@"localizedModel: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models) an updated list that shows all the hardware identifiers.